# Creating different frequency pulses

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I want to create simultaneously working different frequenced pulses with my uno.I've just setup something like below.When i execute the program on uno both of the functions are working with the same frequency.I want one of them create a High value for 1 second then goes Low and the other one of them create a high for 1ms then goes Low.Is this possible?If it is,then how?

```
    int dirPin = 8;
    int stepPin = 9;


    void setup()
    {
      pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
      pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT);

    }
    void stepper()
    {
      digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
      delay(1);
      digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
      delay(1);
    }
    void dir()
    {

          digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH);
          delay(1000);
          digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW);
          delay(1000);

    }
    void loop()
    {
//interrupts functions from here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Referenc/Interrupts
    noInterrupts();
    dir();
    interrupts();
    stepper();     


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code isn't working since it calls `dir()` and `stepper()` sequentially, ie, it only calls `stepper()` after waiting the two seconds for a full cycle of `dir()`.

To simulate calling both at once you should do it the following:

```
void stepForOneSecond(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; ++i){
        digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
        delay(1);
        digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
        delay(1);
    }
}

void loop(){
    digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH);
    stepForOneSecond();
    digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH);
    stepForOneSecond();
}
```

The call to `stepForOneSecond` will last (approximately) 1 second, after which it will toggle the value of the 'dirPin'.